# removing li from ul based on first and/or last name entered in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I want to focus a long `ul` as the user searches for the person they want by their first or last name, by removing list items that dont match. 
My currect code works ok until there is a space in the input field. 
Goal is for user to be able to enter both first and last names, in either order, and have the non-relevant items be cleared. 
problem now is that all items are cleared as soon as there is a space between the first and last names.

html

```
<input id="listCheck">
    <ul class="mylist">
    <li class="entry"><span class="nametext">alex crain</span></li>
    <li class="entry"><span class="nametext">Bart Simpson</span></li>
    <li class="entry"><span class="nametext">Jessica Alba</span></li>
    <li class="entry"><span class="nametext">Will Farrell</span></li>
    </ul>
```

js

```
$('#listCheck').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.mylist>li').each(function(){
     var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(' ');
    var text1 = text[0];
    var text2 = text[1];
        ((text1.indexOf(valThis) == 0) || (text2.indexOf(valThis) == 0)) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();            
   });
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paulmovie/y296xnpk/14/

Comment: I don't think your `text` variable refers to what you think it does. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I got so far. Adding `+ ' '` to `text1`: http://jsfiddle.net/y296xnpk/16/.

Comment: @j08691 sorry im not that experienced. the text var should be the inner text of each span element in the li. not getting any errors. havent seen a need to debug. maybe im missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one more condition is missing here:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luqo/4x8pnqay/)

```
$('#listCheck').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(valThis)
    $('.mylist>li').each(function(){
     var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(' ');
        console.log(text)
    var text1 = text[0];
    var text2 = text[1]; 
    var text3 = text[0] + " " + text[1];
    var text4 = text[1] + " " + text[0];
        ((text1.indexOf(valThis) == 0) || (text2.indexOf(valThis) == 0) || (text3.indexOf(valThis) == 0) || (text4.indexOf(valThis) == 0)) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();            
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky. Since the `space` was taken out, it never got matched.

```
$('#listCheck').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.mylist>li').each(function(){
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase().split(' ');
      var text1 = text[0];
      var text2 = text[1];
      var text3 = text1 + ' ' + text2;  
      ((text2.indexOf(valThis) == 0)) || (text3.indexOf(valThis) == 0)? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();            

    });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y296xnpk/20/).

Comment: That was my first attempt. Check new fiddle! You are welcome.

Comment: Ough. @Maximhash is the only one who created "in either order but both". %)P

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the input and the list like you do with `toLowerCase` to remove whitespace before the comparison.  I also changed it to use a regular expression.

In your case, the regex is mostly just to simplify the comparison (no need to both with splitting and comparing multiple times)

If you want, you could pretty easily modify this to do a 'fuzzy' search.

```
$('#listCheck').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.mylist>li').each(function(){
        var $this   = $(this);
        var reMatch = new RegExp(valThis.replace(/\s/,''), 'i');
        var text    = $this.text().replace(/\s/, '');

        reMatch.test(text) ? $this.show() : $this.hide();            
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y296xnpk/19/